# PHP - Sessions, shuffle function, and arrays

Tags: php

So I created a quiz that generates a random quote at the end by using the `shuffle()` function.

When I refresh the page, I get a different value from the array, repeatedly.

I want it to stay at the same value.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$answer=array(

"Good job.", 
"Great work!", 
"Excellent."

);

shuffle ($answer);

echo $answer[0];

);
```

What I want is...
For example:

> If the shuffle function generates "**Great work!**" and the page is
>   *REFRESHED*, I want it to stay at "**Great work!**", not to reshuffle.

My guess is the use of cookies and sessions is the answer but I attempted.

```
session_start()
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edited** (still didn't work.)

```
<?php
session_start();

//Array of cars
$answer = array(
"Mercedes", 
"Benz", 
"Honda", 
"Toyota", 
"Nissan", 
"Mazda", 
"Hyundai", 
"Ford", 
"Lexus", 
"Lamborghini", 
"Ferrari", 
"Porche", 
"Mitsubushi", 
"Scion", 
"Chrysler", 
"Jeep", 
"Masarati"
);

 shuffle ($answer);


 if( isset ($_SESSION['myAnswer'])){
    $answer = $_SESSION['myAnswer'];
}
else{
    $_SESSION['myAnswer'] = $answer;
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes of course, if you `shuffle` then it's a randomly different answer every time the code is executed. If you're having trouble implementing a solution using cookies or sessions, let us know in more detail what those problems are.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with cookies. Rather than shuffling the array, we take a random key and then save that into the cookie. Since cookies can be tampered with, we make sure to validate the value appropriately.

```
$answer = array(
  "Good job.", 
  "Great work!", 
  "Excellent."
);


if (isset($_COOKIE['answer'])) {
    $answer_key = $_COOKIE['answer'];
}
if (!isset($answer_key) || !isset($answer[$answer_key])) {
    $answer_key = rand(0, count($answer)-1);
    setcookie('answer', $answer_key, time()+9999);
}

echo $answer[$answer_key];
```

This will only work with arrays whose keys are numeric (0, 1, ..., *n*). Be sure not to output anything (including whitespace) before using [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/setcookie).

Comment: I'm sorry but still, when I refresh there's an error @ljacqu

Comment: @jacqu the error is gone but when I refresh it still randomizes the value again.

Comment: @MartinShaba That's odd; maybe your browser doesn't like creating cookies from localhost. You've almost got the session variant working, so thankfully it's nothing we need to worry about! :)

Comment: I'm using chrome, supports cookies/sessions very well.

Comment: Some browsers are picky about the timestamp stuff. Just leave it out and it "may" work. The other most probably error is the mentioned "output before setcookie" stuff. Do not close your files with `?>` or you may end up with some excess space or line break after it.

Answer (score 0):

The command `session_start()` will only make the session available and is already done in most configurations. What you need to do is implement the actual code for storing your answer into the session and retriev from there if available.

A small sample (not complete code, you might want to do this yourself to lear) could look like this:

```
if( isset $_SESSION["myAnswer"] ){
    $answerIdx = $_SESSION["myAnswer"];
}
else{
    // Do it like you did before...
    $_SESSION["myAnswer"] = $answerIdx;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that I did that exactly but with my variables in there and it failed to work.

Comment: Then please post your code. Your shown code above does not contain the parts in question.

Comment: @ljacqu in the session or in the echo?

Comment: @ljacqu I've already did this to echo it - `<?php echo $answer[0]; ?>`

Comment: @MartinShaba I was mistaken and removed my comments. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ljacqu so do you think you can solve my issue or nah?

Comment: @MartinShaba I'm out of ideas for either variant, so I'm afraid not.

Comment: In your code, you arent storing the index within the array but the array itself, which you again shuffle. You have to work with the selected index, same as in the COOKIE answer, just with $_SESSION.